# Get unique values from multiple columns in single request

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct-values, string-aggregation

I have an employee data with several columns. I have a WebAPI that is reading from this database for a search application that surfaces users. I need to get a list of unique values for 4 of the fields. I am hoping to do this in a single query if possible.

I have 25+ columns but I need the unique values for 4 columns (JobTitle,Department,Position,Group). I just need them return as a comma-separated list.

Sample SQL Server 2016 Table:

```
  Name | JobTitle |  Department  |  Position  |  Group  
 ------|----------|--------------|------------|--------- 
  John |  Partner |  Department1 |  Position1 |  Group1 
  Jane |  Manager |  Department2 |  Position2 |  Group2 
  Joe  |  Analyst |  Department2 |  Position2 |  Group2
```

I want my results to be a single row with a list of unique value that are comma-separated:

## Single row returned

```
Departments: Department1,Department2
JobTitles: Partner,Manager,Analyst
Positions: Position1,Position2
Groups: Group1, Group2
```

Comment: Updated (SQL Server 2016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upto SQL Server 2016, you can use STUFF to concatenate STRING from different row into one Row/Column with a comma separator. This following script will return list of DISTINCT values as per your requirement-

```
SELECT DISTINCT
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.JobTitle FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') JobTitle, 
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.Department FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') Department,
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.Position FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') Position,
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.[Group] FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') [Group]
FROM Employee A
```

If you want to add label before the list of distinct values, use this following script-

```
SELECT 
'JobTitles: ' + B.JobTitle AS  JobTitle,
'Departments: ' + B.Department AS  Department,
'Positions: ' + B.Position AS  Position,
'Groups: ' + B.[Group] AS  [Group]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.JobTitle FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') JobTitle, 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.Department FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') Department,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.Position FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') Position,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + A.[Group] FROM Employee A FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') [Group]
    FROM Employee A
)B
```

Comment: This is great! Worked perfectly!